# Mutiple Values in single enum

Tags: java, performance, enums

I have below enum

```
public enum ApiGroup {
    H("gp"),
    S_CARDS("cards"),
    S_CARDMETADATA("cardmetadata"),
    S_PRODUCTS("products");

    private String value;

    private ApiGroupType(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    private static final List<String> sApiGroups = Arrays
        .asList(ApiGroupType.S_CARDS.value, ApiGroupType.S_CARDMETADATA.value, ApiGroupType.S_PRODUCTS.value );

    public static List<String> getSApiGroupsList() {
        return sApiGroups;
    }
```

Currently, I am fetching the required values via creating List. If any future addition is required to the list, there is a need to add the required values first as enum, then in the list, is there any better way this addition at 2 places can be avoided. By adding value at single place should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your method to the following and delete the `sApiGroups` static list.

```
public static List<String> getSApiGroupsList() {
    return Arrays.stream(values())
            .filter(apiGroup -> apiGroup.name().startsWith("S_"))
            .map(ApiGroup::getValue)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Learn more about the `values()` method in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

**Edit**

As per [@ernest_k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5761558/ernest-k)'s comment, we don't need to *stream* for every call of this method. So can just have:

```
private static final List<String> sApiGroups = Arrays.stream(values())
        .filter(apiGroup -> apiGroup.name().startsWith("S_"))
        .map(ApiGroup::getValue)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

public static List<String> getSApiGroupsList() {
    return sApiGroups;
}
```

Comment: As per my current scenario, I don't need all the values of enum in the list, only selected values, here the list contains only values starting with "S_"

Comment: @Kashyap updated. Added `.filter(apiGroup -> apiGroup.name().startsWith("S_"))`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Kashyap you could use ApiGroup.values() which returns an array of values.